# Getting images from nodejs server with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, centos

**Im having an issue where i can only retrieve image files from nodejs through my outside ip**

This is the only way that works
`` src={`http://<outside ip>:5000/${<img>}`} ``

**I have tried these variations to fix it: (abbreviated for simplicity)**

```
/api/<img>    (the /api/ route is used by nginx to route to nodejs)
localhost:5000/<img>
http://localhost:5000/<img>
http://localhost:5000/api/<img>
http://0.0.0.0:5000/<img>
http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/<img>
http://127.0.0.1:5000/<img>
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/<img>
http://api/<img>
```

**My problem is that i have to expose port 5000 to the outside world for this to work**

I cant figure out why none of the localhost versions are pulling images. Although security is a concern, it seems that speed has taken a massive hit as well.

**Is This an nginx problem? A Centos problem? not allowing localhost to send data? Or am i just doing this wrong?**

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your code, but it could be a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue?

If you're using express for the node service then you can see how to easily configure CORS here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

If you're using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) from React to retrieve the data, you can also try passing using the `"mode": "no-cors"` option like so:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/<img>', {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors', 
}).then(result => {
  // Do whatever you need to do 
}).catch(err => {
  // Handle error
})
```

Comment: not using fetch - instead im using ````<img alt={i} key={i} src={`http://<outside ip>:5000/${img}`}  style={{width: "150px", height: "150px", objectFit: "cover", margin: "auto"}}/>```` inside a .map() function